# Database connection issue, couldn't get the data from database

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: test
*/

// edit these values to match your database information
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "_wp201";

$con = mysql_connect($localhost,$user,$password); 

if (!$con) {
    die("database connection error");
} else {

mysql_select_db($db, $con);

// example query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_author='1'");

// show all posts by author 1 (admin)
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    if($row['post_status'] == "publish") {
    echo "".$row['post_title']." <br />";
    }
  }

}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I'm creating a custom registration page in wordpress. So I create a testing page to test the database connection. But the isn't displaying any out. Why is that so? Please help. (All the server into is correct)

Answer (score 0):

try `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`

oh and are you sure there are any rows in the database containing these data?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. I double checked the database.

Comment: so nothing is printed on the page? check the source that no empty values are printed and maybe try `var_dump($result);`

Comment: Is it because Wordpress has their own database intergrated'

Comment: no, WordPress uses a MySQL database which you could access not using WordPress. What is the html source of the page in the browser?

Comment: <html><head></head><body></body></html>

Comment: add `or die(mysql_error())` after `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author='1'")`. Maybe there is an error and so because of that nothing is showed. I think it could be because of the quotes in `post_author='1'`. This is probably an integer, removing the quotes could fix it

Comment: so no error either? And did you change `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: then maybe try checking if 1 row or more is returned with the function `mysql_num_rows($result)`. I still think zero rows are returned

Comment: some like this: `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { /* insert while*/ } else {echo 'No rows found.';}`

Answer (score 0):

Stop using [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) functions, they will be deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.

---

Use WordPress [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) instead.

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( 
  "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
   WHERE post_author=1" 
);
```

---

The WordPress way to do it using [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: test
*/

$myquery = new WP_Query( array(
  'author' => 1,
  'post_status' => 'publish'
  ) );

while( $myquery->have_posts() ):
  $myquery->the_post();
  echo get_the_title() . '<br />';
endwhile;
```

Comment: I've tried replacing it with the code that you've provide, the result is still the same.

Comment: do a `var_dump($myrows);` and tell me what's the results please.

Comment: <?php
/*
Template Name: test
*/

// edit these values to match your database information
$server = "localhost";
$user = "xxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$db = "_wp201";

$con = mysql_connect($localhost,$user,$password); 

if (!$con) {
    die("database connection error");
} else {

mysql_select_db($db, $con);

// example query
$myquery = new WP_Query( array(
  'author' => 2,
  'post_status' => 'publish'
  ) );

while( $myquery->have_posts() ):
  $myquery->the_post();
  echo get_the_title() . '<br />';
endwhile;

var_dump($myrows);
  
}
mysql_close($con);
?>

Comment: You only need what I added. No more `mysql_connect` and stuff. Copy and paste the code I gave you above which uses `WP_Query`.

Comment: I returns NULL, why is that so? Can I use back the same code for my custom registration page in my site?

Comment: Null? Probably no results found. I'd recommend you to read about available [wordpress functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) before.

Comment: The code does show the title of the post. But WP_Query only can be used on blog related function right? I'm currently working on a registration page, where the user can store their info in a custom table inside wordpress db. I need to use $wpdb instead of WP_Query right? Do you have a copy of the codes so that I can refer to?

Comment: You can use `WP_Query` wherever you can use `$wpdb`... If you want WordPress function in an external file, add `define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); require('wp-blog-header.php');` at the start of the file. link to your `wp-blog-header.php` file

Comment: Can you help me with my registration page? I can upload the code and database sample and post the link here.